# Ajax calling through jquery in Struts2

Tags: struts2

Issue is I have 3 dropdowns and I have set my second combo box through a map retrieved from action class , Now I am getting a values as 0 or 1 if I use

```
var sub_cat=$("#selecSubCat").val(); //id for second text box is the selecSubCat
```

How do i get my text value and not 0 and 1 for selected option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, To get text of option you select

```
var v= $("#selecSubCat option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionClass.class

```
private Map usernameList=new HashMap();

public Map getUsernameList() {
    usernameList=new HashMap();
    usernameList.put("1","ram");
    usernameList.put("2","jhon");
    return usernameList;
}

public void setUsernameList(Map usernameList) {
    this.usernameList = usernameList;
}
```

if you are not specifically mentioned listKey,listValue it default take map key as listKey and  map value is listValue.

```
  <s:select  id="selecSubCat" label="Select UserName "
    listKey="value" listValue="value"
    // listKey="key" listValue="value"   // default assigned map value like this
    list="usernameList" 
    name="yourSearchEngine" 
    value="defaultSearchEngine" />
```

now try it,

```
   var sub_cat=$("#selecSubCat").val();
```

it should give your text value

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
$('#selecSubCat'.children("option").filter(":selected").text();
```